# How to solve logarithms equations

Tags: logarithms

I've some problems with solving of those logarithms equations:

1) $\ln(x+1)\le x$

2) $x^2-8\ln(x)=0$

Comment: By solve what do you mean? numerical or Lambert functions? or some other analysis

Comment: @Chinny84 just finding the X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 consider the function
$$
f(x)=\ln(x+1)-x
$$
defined over $(-1,\infty)$, whose derivative is
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}-1=-\frac{x}{x+1}
$$
Can you find the absolute maximum?

For 2 consider the function
$$
g(x)=x^2-8\ln x
$$
defined over $(0,\infty)$, whose derivative is
$$
g'(x)=2x-\frac{8}{x}=\frac{2(x^2-4)}{x}
$$
Can you find the absolute minimum? What can you deduce?